# Passing a value from a page to another in dash plotly

Tags: python, python-2.7, plotly-dash

I have two pages in dash plotly, and an index file who run the pages :

- Index.py
- Page 1
- Page 2

I have a variable in page 1 which I want to pass it in page 2 and work with it. ( example of code)
Is it possible in Dash plotly ?
I saw somewhere that I can use Dcc.store, but how can I stock this variable in it ?

```
First_page = html.Div([
html.Div([dcc.Input(id='date_start', type='text', value='2021')]),
...
...
])

@app.callback(
    Output('someoutput', 'children'),
    [Input('someinput', 'value')])

#Uploading a certain table
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable', 'data'),
    Input('someinput', 'value'))

def function(somedata):
    #Get the VARIABLE
...
...
    variable= 12 (result of the operation in funtion)
```

---

How can I get the  VARIABLE value (12) and inject it in page 2 please ?

```
Second_page = html.Div([
html.Div([dcc.Input(id='', type='text', value='')]),
...
...
])

@app.callback ()

def function_page2(somedata_page2):
    #Work with the VARIABLE in first page
...
```

Thank you .